# How can I perform an UPSERT using Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, upsert, azure-cosmosdb

Azure DocumentDB does not support UPSERT. Is there a reasonable work around to achieve the same functionality?

Is using a stored procedure which checks if the document exists to determine whether and insert or update should be performed an effective strategy?

What if I need to perform thousands of these in bulk?

---

Vote for the feature here:

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/7075256-provide-for-upsert

---

**Update** - Here is my attempt at a bulk upsert stored procedure.

```
function bulkImport(docs) { 
    var collection = getContext().getCollection(); 
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink(); 
    var count = 0; 

    if (!docs) throw new Error('Docs parameter is null'); 

    var docsLength = docs.length; 
    if (docsLength == 0) { 
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(0); 
    } 

    tryUpsert(docs[count], callback); 

    function tryUpsert(doc, callback) {

        var query = { query: ""select * from root r where r.id = @id"", parameters: [ {name: ""@id"", value: doc.id}]};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, function(err, resources, options) {
            if (err) throw err;                           

            if(resources.length > 0) {
                // Perform a replace       
                var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(resources[0]._self, doc, callback);     
                if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);                          
            }
            else {
                // Perform a create
                var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, doc, callback);   
                if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);                             
            }
        });  

        if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count); 
    }

    function callback(err, doc, options) { 
        if (err) throw err; 

        // One more document has been inserted, increment the count. 
        count++; 

        if (count >= docsLength) { 
            // If we have created all documents, we are done. Just set the response. 
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(count); 
        } else { 
            // Create next document. 
            tryUpsert(docs[count], callback); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (2015-10-06):** [Atomic upsert](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-adds-upsert/) is now supported by Azure DocumentDB.

---

Yes, a store procedure would work great for upsert.

There are even code samples available on DocumentDB's Github:

- Upsert (Optimized for Insert): https://github.com/aliuy/azure-node-samples/blob/master/documentdb-server-side-js/stored-procedures/upsert.js
- Upsert (Optimized for Replace): https://github.com/aliuy/azure-node-samples/blob/master/documentdb-server-side-js/stored-procedures/upsertOptimizedForReplace.js
- Bulk Import / Upsert:
  https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-hadoop/blob/master/src/BulkImportScript.js

Comment: Great, thanks. I was on the path of merging these concepts into the bulk import script. Are there significant performance gains from sending a collection of docs to a proc which performs each insert vs. calling the proc one a time from my code? Perhaps it reduces the RUs?

Comment: Sending a collection of documents (as compared to one at a time) can result in a large performance gain by reducing the number of network round trips between your application and the database. However, the difference in terms of RU is negligible.

Comment: The links are dead.

Comment: The script sample repository has moved to: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/tree/master/samples

Comment: where did the bulk upsert gone @AndrewLiu. It is not even in the link or github repo

Comment: @AtulChaudhary I fixed the first 2 links