# Upsert of Mongo API not working with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, upsert

This code is working fine on my local machine.

```
 Bulk.find({"xyz":23}).upsert().update({$set : 5465}); 

 Bulk.execute(function (err, data) {});
```

When I have moved this code to Azure, it wasnt working. I recognize that cosmosDB doesn't support upsert. Is that ryt ?

Reference :
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#database-commands

Should i replace with find and insert or update as normal ? or is there any other solution available ? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, based on the doc [MongoDB query language support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#mongodb-query-language-support) , `upsert()` command is not supported by cosmos db mongo api. As I known, no shortcuts here so far. You need to encapsulate methods to determine whether a document exists, and then decide to insert or update.

Or, just to declare that the Cosmos Document DB SDK supports `Upsert` method. Please refer to the case: [How can I perform an UPSERT using Azure DocumentDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586399/how-can-i-perform-an-upsert-using-azure-documentdb?rq=1).
Cosmos Document DB is a good choice if you could do data migrations.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Does Cosmos DB Mongo API still not support upserts? I want to do it from Databricks/Spark.